# I want to connect the Telegesis USB stick to this silabs kit over zigbee home automation profile.

Tags: zigbee

I want to connect the Telegesis USB stick to this silabs kit over zigbee home automation profile. And i had convert it  into home automation profile in Telegesis Terminal and both behave as coordinator into their configuration and  can’t connect the network into ember Desktop. Anyone had done before,please help me.

Answer (score 1):

A coordinator is a device that creates a personal area network (PAN) and may permit other devices to join that network. When you make both devices behave as coordinator, they are forming separate networks and therefore can not communicate with each other. Even if you gave them the same PAN ID, ZigBee has some anti-collision mechanisms built into the protocol so that they will "know" the networks are distinct and not allow any crossover.

What you should do is configure one of the two as a router or end device. These device types join the network created by the coordinator. The coordinator may need to be in a pairing or "permit joining" mode to allow this. This would be standard commissioning for the Home Automation profile that you want to use.